# android : can't delete and remove sharedpreferences file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

i have posting question in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441220/cant-remove-sharedpreferences) but i got nothing, so i decide to make a new question for searching other solution.

this is my case : First, I was using Shared preferences for my application for sending data from one activity to another, when listview is clicked in first activity, it will going to detail. when other list is clicked, it will going to first data that i've clicked before it. then i realize if i use sharedpreferences for sending data from one activity to other activity, it will save in device memory, so i change my code and decide to use intent, but my sharedpreferences's file is not remove. when list is clicked, it will going to first data that i've clicked when i use shared preferences.
 I have used:

```
settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

and

```
settings.edit().remove().commit();
```

but i think it doesn't work. this is my first activity using intent:

```
public class TerbaruSimasCard extends ListActivity {
    String nama1,alamat1,ket1,img_id1,telp1,begdate1,enddate1;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ArrayList<TerbaruModel>ListTerbaru;
    ListView list;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //hide title bar
            BasicDisplaySettings.toggleTaskBar(TerbaruSimasCard.this, false);
            //show status bar
            BasicDisplaySettings.toggleStatusBar(TerbaruSimasCard.this, true);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
            settings.edit().clear().commit();

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.terbarusimascard);
            ListTerbaru= new ArrayList<TerbaruModel>();
            new TerbaruAsyncTask().execute();
     }
    public class TerbaruAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String url = ("http://www.abc.xyz/sc_merchant.htm?s=3&d=25");

        public TerbaruAsyncTask() {
            this.url=url;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute (){ 
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TerbaruSimasCard.this,"", "melakukan pengambilan data...");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = "";
            try {
                result= Connection.get(url);
            } catch (Exception e){
                result = "";
                Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
            }
            return result;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        fetchResponse(result.replace("\n","").trim());
        dialog.dismiss();
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent detail= new Intent (TerbaruSimasCard.this, TerbaruDetail.class);

                detail.putExtra("nama", nama1);
                detail.putExtra("alamat",alamat1);
                detail.putExtra("ket", ket1);
                detail.putExtra("telp",telp1);
                detail.putExtra("begdate", begdate1);
                detail.putExtra("enddate",enddate1);
                detail.putExtra("img_id", img_id1);

                System.out.println(nama1);

                startActivity (detail); 
            }
        });
    }


    }

private void fetchResponse (String result){
    if (!result.equals("")){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            TerbaruModel LT=null;
            for (int i= 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject= jsonArray.getJSONObject (i);

                LT= new TerbaruModel (jsonObject.optString("kat"),
                        img_id1=jsonObject.optString("img_id"),
                        nama1= jsonObject.optString("nama"),
                        alamat1=jsonObject.optString("alamat"),
                        ket1=jsonObject.optString("ket"),
                        jsonObject.optString("tgl"),
                        jsonObject.optString("accday"),
                        telp1=jsonObject.optString("telp"),
                        begdate1=jsonObject.optString("begdate"),
                        enddate1=jsonObject.optString("enddate")
                        );
                ListTerbaru.add(LT);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);



setListAdapter (new TerbaruAdapter(this, ListTerbaru));
        }
```

this is for detail:

```
 public class TerbaruDetail extends Activity {
    String nama1,alamat1,ket1,img_id1,telp1,begdate1,enddate1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
        //hide title bar
        BasicDisplaySettings.toggleTaskBar(TerbaruDetail.this, false);
        //show status bar
        BasicDisplaySettings.toggleStatusBar(TerbaruDetail.this, true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailviewer);

        Intent detail= getIntent();
        nama1=detail.getStringExtra("nama");
        alamat1= detail.getStringExtra("alamat");
        ket1= detail.getStringExtra("ket");
        img_id1= detail.getStringExtra("img_id");
        telp1= detail.getStringExtra("telp");
        begdate1= detail.getStringExtra("begdate");
        enddate1= detail.getStringExtra("enddate");

        System.out.println(nama1+"nama");
        TextView detail_phone=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_phone);
        TextView detail_begdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.begdate);
        TextView detail_enddate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.endate);
        TextView detail_name =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_name);    
        TextView detail_adress =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_adress);    
        TextView keterangan =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.keterangan);  
        ImageView detail_img_id= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_kategori);


        detail_name.setText(nama1);
        detail_phone.setText(telp1);
        detail_begdate.setText(begdate1);
        detail_enddate.setText(enddate1);
        detail_adress.setText(alamat1);
        keterangan.setText(ket1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You do not mind just delete the app then reload the apk.

From what I know the Shared Preferences value will remain until you uninstall an app.

If the above did not work then try to deleted manually

> /data/data/com.package.name/shared_prefs/PREFS_NAME.xml

Comment: i have clear cache and uninstall it, but my sharedprefences still saved in device

Comment: if try to delete via ddms... but it still save in my device.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` will not delete the **sharedpreferences file**, it only clears the  contents in this file.

If you really want to delete this file, you should use file operation , sharedprefereces file location is `/data/data/com.yourpackage.name/shared_prefs/filename.xml`.  **BTW, you'd better use intent to send data between activities.**

Comment: if try to delete via ddms... but it still save in my device.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear out your data (because it is corrupt or whatever), you can do that manually from the home screen.  setting -> application manager -> "your app" -> clear data